# Ads not showing on iPhone5

Tags: ios, adbannerview

i am showing adds in my app, but adds are not showing in `iPhone5 device` only showing in `simulator`.

i am using code like this -

```
-(void)showAdds
{
   {

    if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad))
    {

        bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(128.0,
                                               670 ,
                                               GAD_SIZE_728x90.width,
                                               GAD_SIZE_728x90.height)];
        bannerView.adUnitID = @"8c9b7de0880d478b";
    }
    else {

        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
        {
            bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120,
                                                   [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - GAD_SIZE_320x50.height ,
                                                   GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                                   GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
            bannerView.adUnitID = @"a151d69e8127bd7";
            NSLog(@"ads");
        }
        else
        {
            bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,
                                                   [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - GAD_SIZE_320x50.height ,
                                                   GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                                   GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
            bannerView.adUnitID = @"a151d69e8127bd7";
            NSLog(@"ads");

        }

    }
```

adds are showing on simulator but not on iPhone device. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are use the test ads, after IOS 6 Test ads is not support the Device , Please disable the test ads , then you see the ads in real device 
see this link    https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#ios-testing

Comment: Test ads? how to disable it for iOS 7?

Comment: see this link for test